# Oracle Trigger to remove stock quantity from products and add to orderline

Tags: oracle, join, triggers

I apologise in advance for this confusing question, wall of text, and awful trigger. I'm designing a small database for a retail store that takes orders in-store and then delivers the products from the onsite warehouse/stockroom.

Now the order entity has a one-to-many relationship to an order_line entity which in turn has a many to one relationship with product (which itself is stored in the stock etc).  The order_line entity is the link entity and solves the many-to-many relationship so that's all good. Just to clarify, it's one order_line per product.

What I want to do is when an order_line (which has a quantity attribute) is created, I want the trigger to first check the appropriate product has sufficient stock (so if quantity is 3, stock must be at least 3), otherwise it must throw an error.

If successful I want it to update the quantity and stock attributes accordingly. I'd also like it to add a subtotal value to the order_line (I've yet to attempt this) which in turn can then be used to calculate the total value in the order entity.

So at this stage I'm looking for a bit of guidance because I'm quite confused with this, now.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_order_line  
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON order_line 

for each row
BEGIN 
select order_line.quantity, products.stock from order_lines right join products on       order_line.product_no=products.product_no;
if(order_line.quantity>products.stock) then
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20103, 'Insufficient Stock');
ELSE
products.stock := products.stock - quantity;
 dbms_output.put('Successful');
END IF;
END; 
. 
run
```

**Errors I am getting:**

```
2/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/49     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
3/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
3/15     PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'ORDER_LINE.QUANTITY'
     not allowed in this context
```

**What I've tried:**

- I'm not sure about the first two errors; the table in question is
  definitely called order_line, perhaps I've missed something obvious.
- I've also tried declaring variables for products.stock and order_line
  quantity to solve the last error - this compiles IIRC but doesn't
  actually work as I guess it's not updating the table.
- I'm not worried so much about the else action, I probably need an update
  table statement there but for now I'm just focusing on getting the
  trigger condition to work.
- If any one could point me in the right
  direction and point out any hilarious errors I'd appreciate it.

  Thank you very much for your time, I apologise for scarring your eyes with this monstrosity of a trigger.

Comment: What's that `run` command at the end? Which tool are you using to execute your CREATE TRIGGER?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a constraint on products.stock to enforce the value is > -1:

```
ALTER TABLE products add CONSTRAINT has_stock CHECK (stock >-1);
```

Then do the `update` and `insert` as a single transaction.

```
UPDATE product SET products.stock = products.stock - quantity_required
WHERE product_id=id_of_product

INSERT INTO order_line ...............

COMMIT;
```

The transaction will always fail if there is not enough stock, and you will not have the problems associated with triggers.

Assuming you do not have the stock price at this point you could get it by using the `RETURNING` clause on your `update` (you will need to DECLARE the variable `v_product_cost` to hold the value) e.g:

```
UPDATE product SET products.stock = products.stock - quantity_required
WHERE product_id=id_of_product
RETURNING products.value INTO v_product_cost
```

You can then use this value in the insert that follows.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I'll add the constraint, thanks for that. That seems like a simple, base-level solution which will work perfectly. I'll give the update a try tomorrow. Thanks for responding, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `run` command at the end doesn't make sense.  That's SQL Server syntax.
2. In your query, you're referencing a table `ORDER_LINES` (plural).  But the trigger is defined on a table `ORDER_LINE` (singular).  I assume that you don't have both an `ORDER_LINE` and an `ORDER_LINES` table so I expect that you intended your query to reference the `ORDER_LINE` table.
3. A row-level trigger defined on table A cannot in general query table A.  So since your trigger is defined on `ORDER_LINE`, it cannot query `ORDER_LINE`.  It appears that you really just want the information about the row that caused the trigger to fire so you don't actually need to join to the `ORDER_LINE` table.  You just need to reference attributes from the `:NEW` record.
4. A `SELECT` statement in PL/SQL needs to do something with the results.  Presumably, your intention is to do a `SELECT ... INTO` a local variable.
5. If you want to update the `PRODUCTS` table, you'd need to do an actual `UPDATE`.

Putting all that together, my guess is that you're trying to create a trigger that looks something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_order_line  
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON order_line 
  for each row
DECLARE
  l_current_stock products.stock%type;
BEGIN 
  select products.stock 
    into l_current_stock
    from products
   where product_no = :new.product_no;
  if(:new.quantity > l_current_stock) then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20103, 'Insufficient Stock');
  else
    update products
       set stock := stock - :new.quantity
     where product_no := :new.product_no;
  end if;
END;
```

All that being said, however, a trigger would not generally be the correct way to solve this sort of problem.  From a maintenance standpoint if nothing else, having a stored procedure `PROCESS_ORDER` that inserts all the `ORDER_LINE` rows and updates all the `PRODUCTS` rows will be much easier to follow and debug.  The more business logic that is embedded in triggers the harder it is to follow the flow of the application and the easier it is to end up with a rat's nest of unintentional updates that are nearly impossible to unwind.

Also, be aware of what happens in a multi-user system.  Session A can query the `PRODUCTS` table and see a `STOCK` of 5 and accept an order for 4 units of that product.  But before session A issues a commit, session B also queries the same row of the `PRODUCTS` table, sees the same `STOCK` of 5, and accepts an order for 3 units.  Session B's `UPDATE` statement will block until session A commits.  But then if A commits and B commits, both orders will have been entered and the `PRODUCTS` table will show a `STOCK` of -2.  That's why you need the `CHECK` constraint that Kevin suggested

```
ALTER TABLE products
  ADD CONSTRAINT chk_positive_stock CHECK( stock >= 0 );
```

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for spotting the Order_lines typo - you're right, I only use order_line in this system. In regards to point 3, I see what you mean, I think I'd get a table mutating error, so I'll look into your suggestion. Point 4: That makes sense.

Sadly the coursework specification requires three triggers, no marks are awarded for procedures (it seems silly to me) and this is my third trigger. If it was you, would you bother making a trigger for this function (if a procedure was not an option)? The reasons you gave are making me think I should look at another idea.